# Keras - ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM'

Tags: keras, keras-layer, cudnn

I am trying to use the CuDNNLSTM Keras cell to improve training speed for a recurrent neural network (doc [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm)).

When I run:

```
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, CuDNNLSTM
```

I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM'

My configuration is Keras 2.0.8, python 3.5, tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0 (all managed by Anaconda) and I have both CUDA 8.0 and cudnn 6.0 installed that should be OK with the nvidia dependencies of tensorflow ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases)). My code setup makes Keras effectively use tensorflow backend, and every layer except the ones starting with CuDNN* work fine.

Anyone has an idea about the source of this import error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out keras 2.0.8 doesn't have the code for these kind of layers that came in more recent versions.

I used pip to upgrade to the lastest version:

```
pip install --upgrade keras
```

and it all works now.

Answer (score 16):

And for Tensorflow-2: You can just use LSTM with no activation function and it will automatically use the CuDNN version

Comment: thanks. is the case same for CuDNNGRU? and any source you can point me to, to prove this to my teammates.

Answer (score 2):

These layers have been deprecated in the latest versions.
For a detailed tutorial you can see [this](https://keras.io/guides/working_with_rnns/#performance-optimization-and-cudnn-kernels) Keras guide

Answer (score 1):

in conda it will be (as of nov 2019)

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install keras==2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM`

I was also facing the same prob. i use the above code and now it is working