# tensorflow.keras.layers: ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

Please I tried importing CuDnnLSTM from **tensorflow.keras.layers** to increase my training speed but got this error. I know similar question has been asked by a user with Keras 2.0.8 and python 3.5.

My configuration is tensorflow version 2.0.0-beta1 and Python 3.6.10.

**This is what I tried:** from tensorflow.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM

And I got this error,
**ImportError**: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM'

Please any one has idea on how to fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras - ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857437/keras-importerror-cannot-import-name-cudnnlstm)

Comment: I tried the solution suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857437/keras-importerror-cannot-import-name-cudnnlstm: THIS IS WHAT I DID, !pip install --upgrade keras on colab. still got: (ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM')

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `from tensorflow.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM` you can use `from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM`.

Please refer working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(1, return_sequences=0, input_shape=(1, 1)))
print(model.summary())
```

Output:

```
2.0.0-beta1
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm (CuDNNLSTM)       (None, 1)                 16        
=================================================================
Total params: 16
Trainable params: 16
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: @Complex1234, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You